# Wrong labels when using dataloader pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, dataloader

I have the following code:

```
def get_relevant_indicies(dataset):
    """Returns the indicies of the classes in the dataset"""
    indicies = []
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        idx = dataset[i][1]
        indicies.append(idx)
    return indicies

def get_data(batch_size, folder):
    """Takes a batch_size and the name of the folder (name of folder most likely called dataset)
    Example:
    get_data(1, "~/aps360-proj/dataset")
    
    """
    classes = ("testing1", "testing2", "testing3")
    
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]
    )
    #Load images
    trainset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(folder, transform=transform)    
    #Get indicies of images
    relevant_train_indicies = get_relevant_indicies(trainset)

    np.random.seed(1)
    np.random.shuffle(relevant_train_indicies)
    random_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(relevant_train_indicies)
    for i in random_sampler:
        print(i)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, sampler=random_sampler)
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        print(labels)
```

The output for the two print statements differ and I'm not sure why. For random_sampler it outputs 0->2 as expected since there are three folders but after passing this into dataloader it outputs 0->1 only

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to say what you wanted to achieve with the `get_relevant_indicies` function.

Your `get_relevant_indicies` function returns a list of *labels* for each sample in the dataset. That’s what `dataset[i][1]` returns for the ImageFolder dataset - the target label for the image (the image itself would be in `dataset[i][0]`.

You are then using these labels (so either 0, 1 or 2) as data indices, which is 100% not what you meant to do.